# How do I send more than one pageview request to Google Analytics at one time?

Tags: google-analytics

It's very easy to track a pageview with GA like:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'], ['_trackPageview', '/p1']);
```

But is it possible to send more than one page at the same time so that there won't be too many HTTP requests?

Expected implementation as:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'], ['_trackPageview', ['/p1', '/p2', '/p3']]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Your first line of code is actually sending in two pageviews, one for just "/" and the other for "/p1". So in effect you ARE sending in more than one PV. But it's still the same number of HTTP requests. Your second line of code also sends in two pageviews, but both to "/". (Checked via Network tab.) I don't believe it is possible to send multiple PVs with a single HTTP request, but that's what I suspect.

Comment: `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'], ['_trackPageview', '/p1'], ['_trackPageview', '/p2'], ['_trackPageview', '/p3']);` - maybe this way?

Comment: Surprisingly (to me), that does send multiple virtual pageviews, but still each in separate HTTP requests it looks like. Again, you should check the Network tab to confirm.